# Admob and targetSDKVersion

Tags: android, admob

The more I read about this, the more I get confused. It seems easy while reading, but few seconds later, it just bounces over my head. Anyway, here is my question.

I have a published app, and I wish to add admob advertising to it. As far as I read, i need to have the targetSDKVersion in my manifest file, to be 13 or higher. When i set the targetSDKVersion to 13, eclipse shows me a warning saying,

"Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details."

Well, as of now, this is my understanding of minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion.

minSDKVersion = this is for backward compatability. I have my minSDKVersion set to 10, for Android 2.3.3, which is the version i developed my application. So, people with a minimum of Android version of 2.3.3 will be able to use my application.

targetSDKVersion = this is to tell that I have used a feature in my application, that belonged to the targetSDKVersion and people with versions equal to and above will get to see that feature, where as people with lower versions, will be able to use the application, but doesn't get to see the feature.

So, if my understanding is correct, what about the warning? What does this warning mean?

And also, admob states that it requires a minimum of Android 1.5 or later. But the documentation says, compile against Android version 3.2. What about this?

I am pretty new to android as well as admob, so please bear with me, if these are pretty basic questions.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that warning as `targetSdkVersion` is used to tell the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's `forward-compatibility` with the target version. And now the `targetSdkVersion` version is `16` but you are setting it in `13` so it shows that warning.

If you change it to `16` then or `17` then you will not get that warning.

```
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

You can learn more from here [application's compatibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: I changed the version to 16, it still gives the same warning. I changed it to 17 and there is no warning. Now, whenever there is a higher version available, should I be changing this?

Comment: It depends on your app's functionality. If you need to implement latest version's feature then you can change the targetSdkversion to latest, else you don't need. For working admob's sdk you need to set targetSdkversion to 13 or higher (3.2 android honeycomb or higher), if you set it, will work from 1.5 to 4.2 you don't need to worry about it.